# Whats the correct way to programmatically add permissions to a group

Tags: django, permissions

I want to add (already existing, defined via permissions in the meta tag) permissions to groups and looking for the correct place to do so. I have to assure that after the sync_db command all groups have the correct permissions assigned to.

I was thinking to hook up a post_syncdb signal, but the signal docs say:

> It is important that handlers of this signal perform idempotent
>   changes (e.g. no database alterations) as this may cause the flush
>   management command to fail if it also ran during the syncdb command.

Thus it is probably not advisable that someone adds permissions to a group in a management command called via the sync_db_post signal.

I planned to setup the permissions like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='user_profiles')
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='user_profiles')

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('admin_section_access', 'Access to front-end admin section'),
        )
```

in the management command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = 'none'
    help = 'Sets the defined group permissions'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        front_end_admin_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="Front End Admin")

        #get the content type for the UserProfile model
        user_profile_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='organization', model='userprofile')
        admin_section_access_perm = Permission.objects.get(content_type=user_profile_ct, codename="admin_section_access")
        front_end_admin_group.permissions.add(admin_section_access_perm)
        self.stdout.write('Successfully setup group permissions.')
```

Comment: This operation seems quite static, so plain initial_data fixtured might work for you. If not, the custom command approach you demonstrate above fits nice. To prevent accidents I'd hook into the post_save and pre_delete group signals and ensure the "Front end admin" group never gets deleted and critical permissions are not removed.

Comment: You are probably right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options here. The first is to create a fixture for your database, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) in the Django docs. That's the oldest way to seed data (for you, permissions xref records) into your database.

The second option, and my preferred over the first, is to use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to programmatically track and maintain changes to your database. While most commonly used for schema changes, its [data migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#datamigration) feature is the *perfect* place to handle what you want. You'd run this in your command line: `./manage.py datamigration my_app seed_permissions` and then simply write the Django code required to get your permissions into place within the provided `forwards` function.

The main gotcha to the second option is that it requires you to run the additional command of `migrate` after `sync_db`, but this is probably unavoidable anyway as South is the truth (and slated to become core Django in 1.7).